# OpenMapLayers not rendering map in a MVC project

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, openlayers

I'm trying to start to work on a project based on OpenMapLayers, what i did was going on ther site and copy paste the basic example in a html file and running it, everything works as expected, than I basically tried to do the same on a new MVC project but nothing gets rendered. Any idea on why that happens?

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<h2>Getting started</h2>
<div id="mapdiv"></div>
@section scripts{
    <script src="http://www.openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
    <script>
            map = new OpenLayers.Map("mapdiv");
            map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM());

            var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(-0.1279688, 51.5077286)
                .transform(
                    new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), // transform from WGS 1984
                    map.getProjectionObject() // to Spherical Mercator Projection
                );

            var zoom = 16;

            var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers("Markers");
            map.addLayer(markers);

            markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(lonLat));

            map.setCenter(lonLat, zoom);

    </script>
}
```

Comment: you need the OpenLayer css too

Comment: @JGH thankf for the replay, how's thaty related to MVC?

Comment: it is related to "nothing gets rendered"

Comment: @JGH it didn't solved my issue..by "how is that related to mvc" I mean..in a plain html file the code in my question is working properly, so that's why I was asking, why the css is related to mvc..

Comment: I am intrigue, what is the example of OL you are using?

Comment: @cabesuon https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenLayers_Marker_Example

Comment: ouch, that's version 2.13.1... OpenLayers is at v6 now. See this instead https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/quickstart.html

Comment: agree with @JGH you should use the new library

Comment: @cabesuon oh...thanks to point that out, as I said I'm a totally newbie, I've looked at the link kindly provided by JGH but I can't understand how to put multiple markers on the map, now I'm receiving a json with multiple elements like { "coords": [ { "latitude": 8.417334","longitude": "45.322557" }, { "latitude": "8.411594", "longitude": "45.324352"}]} and I need to put them on the map as markers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I made a example for you, let me know if this is what you are looking for.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.3.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <style>
      .map {
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.3.1/build/ol.js"></script>
    <title>GeoJSON to Points</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      const geojsonObject = {
        'type': 'FeatureCollection',
        'crs': {
          'type': 'name',
          'properties': {
            'name': 'EPSG:3857'
          }
        },
        'features': [
          {
            'type': 'Feature',
            'geometry': {
              'type': 'Point',
              'coordinates': ol.proj.fromLonLat([37.41, 8.82])
            }
          },
          {
            'type': 'Feature',
            'geometry': {
              'type': 'Point',
              'coordinates': ol.proj.fromLonLat([38.41, 9.82])
            }
          },
          {
            'type': 'Feature',
            'geometry': {
              'type': 'Point',
              'coordinates': ol.proj.fromLonLat([37.41, 9.82])
            }
          }
        ]
      };

      const style = new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
          radius: 5,
          fill: null,
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({color: 'red', width: 2})
        })
      });

      const vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
        features: (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(geojsonObject)
      });

      const vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: vectorSource,
        style
      });

      const map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
          }),
          vectorLayer
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
          center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([37.41, 8.82]),
          zoom: 8
        })
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**

If your JSON format is the one you describe in the comments of the question, this should work,

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.3.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <style>
      .map {
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.3.1/build/ol.js"></script>
    <title>JSON to Points</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      const jsonObject = {
        "coords": [
          { "latitude": "8.417334", "longitude": "45.322557" },
          { "latitude": "8.411594", "longitude": "45.324352"}
        ]
      };

      const features = [];

      for(const coord of jsonObject.coords) {
        features.push(new ol.Feature({
          geometry: new ol.geom.Point(
            ol.proj.fromLonLat([coord.longitude, coord.latitude]),
            'XY'
          )
        }));
      }

      const style = new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
          radius: 5,
          fill: null,
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({color: 'red', width: 2})
        })
      });

      const vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
        features
      });

      const vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: vectorSource,
        style
      });

      const map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
          }),
          vectorLayer
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
          center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([45.32, 8.41]),
          zoom: 14
        })
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @cabesoun Thanks very much I think is the right solution but I'm receiving a jSon string from the server, so my coordinates elements inside the json are formed in this way : "coordinates":"ol.proj.fromLonLat([45.31, 8.43])" wich is a string, if I'm transorming it as an object they remains as a string and not like "coordinates":ol.proj.fromLonLat([45.31, 8.43]) as in your example, so they can't be rendered...I'm totally desperate.

Comment: Check the updated answer and let me know if it helps you.

Comment: many thanks! that worked well..where did you find a documentation for using it without nodejs? I'm trying to understand how to add a popup for displaying infos...but all the infos I'm finding is with using NodeJs

Comment: Glad it helps you! .. You just need to import `ol.css` and `ol.js`, then just follow the namespace .. For example, `import { Vector as VectorLayer } from 'ol/layer'` became `ol.layer.Vector` .. BTW, I only use this to build very simple examples